# How to click an element from a group of elements based on the textContent - Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, puppeteer

I want to click on a selected element matching the given text using puppeteer.

The below javascript code is working fine in the browser console.

```
let menuitems = document.querySelectorAll('a[role=menuitem]');

for(i=0; i < menuitems.length; i++){

  if((menuitems[i].textContent).includes("My Content")){
     menuitems[i].textContent.click()

     console.log("found");
   }
}
```

May I know how can I do this using puppeteer?

Comment: The best way is either xpath or switching to playwright which has selectors for this.

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet has a function that uses puppeteer to go to a page and clicks a given element (assuming you entered what you need). Please read comments throughout to see what you need to add.

Puppeteer has some amazing [API doc's](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.3.1/docs/api.md) on their git-hub. Puppeteer is a lot of fun when used to it's full potential. It can do practically anything a normal user can perform on a browser. Have fun!

```js
//Include puppeteer module
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//Function must be async to "await" for page results
const clickElm = async () => {

  let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  //If you want to run puppeteer headless (be able to see whats happening)    pass the set "headless" to "false"
  //let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  
  //Enter your desired URL below
  await page.goto('<your_desired_url>');
   
  //Evaluate the page with page.evaluate()
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    let menuitems = document.querySelectorAll('a[role=menuitem]')

  //For each menu item click (assuming the element is clickable)
    menuitems.forEach(item => {
       if(item.textContent.includes('My Content')){
          item.click()
       }
    }) 
  })
 



}


clickElm();
```